# Understand adding rows on click, confusion with .cloneNode(true);

Tags: javascript

Consider this http://jsfiddle.net/99CL3/224/, Which adds rows on click

**HTML**

```
<br /><br />
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="links" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="keywords" /></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="violationtype" /></td>   
        <td><input type="submit" class="button" value="Add another line" onclick="addField(this);" /></td>          
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
function addField(n)
{
    var tr = n.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('tbl').appendChild(tr);
}
```

I'm trying to understand why this code which adds rows on click actually works.
First I realize that it will take what I click (the input), and go two parent nodes above it.
so the first `.parentNode` points to `td`, and the next to `tr`. So basically we are making a table on click with these new properties. Now my question is basically what is the role of `.cloneNode(true)` here? I have read mozilla documentation, but I can't really understand from their example. Why can't I just append `n.parentNode.parentNode` right away?

Comment: Can you be in 2 different places at once? Well neither can nodes. So yes, you can drop the `.cloneNode(true)`, but then the `.appendChild(tr)` will relocate the `tr` to its new location.

Comment: So without .cloneNode(true) Basically we keep drawing over the same row?

Comment: Basically yes. If you have a table with a single row, and you say append that row to the same table, you're basically telling it to remove that row from that table and place it back in as the last row, which of course will still be the only row. If there were 10 rows, and you did that to the first row, you're now telling it to remove that row from the table and add it as the last child, so it will be removed from its position as the first child and will become the last child.

Comment: Remember that none of this has anything to do with HTML. Your HTML becomes irrelevant as soon as it arrives at the browser and gets parsed. You're now dealing with a tree structure of objects that represent the elements you described using HMTL tags.

Comment: I think I get it! Basically n.parentNode.parentNode, targets the tr we just drew. But we don't want to draw the one we just drew on click, we need a new one! So we create a copy with .cloneNode. Right?

Comment: Yes, though "drawing" is more what the browser does in response to the nodes you move around. We just manipulate them by creating, removing, relocating, changing property values, etc.. As we do that, the browser updates the view by redrawing the page to reflect our changes. But yes, if we want a new node added that looks identical to an existing one, it's not enough to move that node. We need to copy it, and then move that copy to wherever we want it.

Comment: This doesent work in I.E I just realized.. Anyway I can make this work in I.E?

Comment: Should work in IE. Which version? What happens? Any console errors?

Comment: No errors. The rows simply don't add. I tried in mozilla and chrome and it works fine. It was on a work computer, i'm not sure how old, but those computers only run super old i.e since not everyone has admin rights. I'm guessing its an issue with .cloneNode(true), I've used .parentNode before with i.e and it works ok on those computers

Comment: Hmm... don't know why that would be. Make sure you're not in quirks mode by including `<!doctype HTML>` at the top of the page if you haven't.

Comment: All right, I'll try tommorow and let you know!

Comment: Still doesent work. Looks like cloneNode has issues with I.e after googling. Do you know of any alternative methods?

Comment: Surprisingly enough its I.E 11

Comment: Odd. It [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/kc57fvka/) in IE11. You could try using [`.outerHTML` with `.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://jsfiddle.net/kc57fvka/1/), but that'll almost definitely fail in older versions of IE. Otherwise, just have your function manually create the new row and cells.

Comment: Does I.e have some weird capability error of not being able to read php or from oracle mysql? I have one of my <td> </td> Reading from an oracle database. Works fine in Chrome and mozilla though.

Comment: It shouldn't. The only thing that may trip up a browser is invalid HTML, but even that is well-defined as to how browsers should respond.

Comment: Still doesent work with that new code you posted. This is so weird.

Comment: Sorry, just not sure. You should probably put together a complete yet minimal demonstration of the issue and post a question about it.

Comment: Ok. Its clearly reaching the function too. I put an alert in the function to do onclick.

Comment: When I alert tr after var tr = n.parentNode.parentNode in i.e it alerts [Object], when I alert in chrome Nothing even alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element is unique. if you don't clone the element then the element is *moved* to the target location. So using `clone` here is necessary for creating *another* row.

Comment: "if you don't clone the element then the element is moved to the target location", sorry I don't really get what that means, could you elaborate?

Comment: @cresjoy I meant the element is detached from it's current location and becomes child of another element. In this case you don't create another element, you are moving the element to another location. One node can not be child of 2 other nodes.

Comment: Why doesen't this piece of code work in I.E? It works fine on chrome and mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

**.cloneNode(true)** duplicate the selected [tr] tag, if you remove it, your code however works but its behavior is different because the [tr] you selected already belongs to your table.

By the way, you should change name/id of cloned row's input, to make them unique.

p.s: your jsfiddle has only one parentNode, instead of two.